# Testing Batch Apex with Big Objects

Tags: batch, big-object

I have a batch apex class that uses Big Objects for processing. However, when running tests on this batch class, Salesforce throws an error not allowing Big Objects to be inserted for testing:  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bigobjects.meta/bigobjects/big_object_populate_apex.htm

Anyone knows how to run testing on Batch apex that works with Big Objects without having to previously insert Big Objects in the test?

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/247750/creating-bigobject-record-in-test-class-using-test-loaddata

Comment: Did you tried stub API?https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.218.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_stub_api.htm

Comment: The problem with Apex stub API is that I would have to mock the big object insert, this would mean having to stub the calls in the Database namespace, which does not seem possible

Comment: You should use a selector pattern which can be mocked to return big objects. ApexMocks on GitHub is an excellent framework to do this (leverages stubAPI)